# Show form success after submit in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

My error messages works well, but I do not know how to output success message NOT in a session's flash data.

```
<div class="tpl-callbacks" id="tpl-callback">
    <?php
        if( $this->session->flashdata('message') )
            $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        if( $this->session->flashdata('error') )
            $error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
        if( $this->session->flashdata('success'))
            $success = $this->session->flashdata('success');
        // THIS WORKS WITHOUT FLASHDATA
        if(function_exists('validation_errors') && validation_errors() != '')
            $error = validation_errors();
        // AND HOW TO DO THE SAME BUT FOR SUCCESS AND WITHOUT FLASHDATA ?
    ?>
    <?php if( !empty($error) ):?>
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <?php echo $error;?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if( !empty($success) ):?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <?php echo $success;?>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

So whenever I do a form check after submit, i can output errors message and success message in flashdata, but I do not know how to show a success message without using the flashdata:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    // $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors()); // <-- THIS WORKS IN FLASHDATA
    validation_errors(); <-- THIS WORKS BUT WITHOUT FLASHDATA, WHICH IS GOOD ALSO
}else{
    // Set the callback message
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Success!'); // <-- THIS WORKS IN FLASHDATA
    // AND HOW I SHOULD DO THE SAME, BUT WITHOUT FLASHDATA ?
    // SO IT WILL WORK WITH MY MAIN TEMPLATE.PHP

}
```

Could someone point me out to the correct answer, or give me a tips what to checkout to achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you post the form on same page?

Comment: @sbaaaang - i tried that, and it works, the problem was only that i didn't know how to do it on the same page before

Comment: ehehe no problems, hope you fixed anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are not redirecting, then you could use a variable and throw it to your view. So it could be something like this in your controller:

```
$messages = array();
$messages[] = "My message";

$view_data['messages'] = $messages;
$this->load->view('your view', $view_data);
```

In your view, the messages array will be available and you can use it.

However, if you want to do a redirect, you need to store it temporarily somewhere to keep it alive between your requests. The session flashdata in codeigniter is very suitable for this.

The validation_errors(); in your control doesn't do anything by the way. Since you do not echo it. The fact that it probably worked is probably because you also used that function in your view.

Comment: Great! So simple, I do not know how I didn't realized that before